# Xamarin - ImageButton doesnt activate every click

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, mobile, imagebutton

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5drGc.png)

On the picture above you can see where the ImageButton sometimes activates. When I spam clicking in the blue area the counter sometimes increases. I think there might be another Layer on top of the ImageButton but I dont know how to fix it. Below there is the XAML code. Hopefully somebody can help. Thanks!

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="Discover" TextColor="Black" FontSize="24" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="15" />

    <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding plants}" HeightRequest="300" PeekAreaInsets="100">
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Frame  HeightRequest="280" WidthRequest="180" BackgroundColor="Wheat" HasShadow="True" Margin="10" Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" CornerRadius="10" >
                        <Grid>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <ImageButton Source="{Binding imgsource}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                    Aspect="AspectFill" Opacity="0.8" Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked"/>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout Margin="0,10" >

                                <Image Source="https://icons-for-free.com/iconfiles/png/512/bookmark-131964752402712733.png" HeightRequest="35"
                       Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="5,-15"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding name_norm}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="16" FontAttributes="Bold"
                       Margin="15,-10,0,0" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" />

                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="15,-8,0,0" >
                                    <Image Source="https://www.freeiconspng.com/thumbs/info-icon/info-icon-24.png" HeightRequest="15"
                       Aspect="AspectFit"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding name_lat}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="16" FontAttributes="Italic"  VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="-5,0" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
    <Label x:Name="label" Text="0 ImageButton clicks"
           FontSize="Large"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

Here the C# Code:

```
namespace PlantBase
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int clickTotal;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clickTotal += 1;
        label.Text = $"{clickTotal} ImageButton click{(clickTotal == 1 ? "" : "s")}";
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [VisualElement.InputTransparent Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.inputtransparent?view=xamarin-forms).

> `false` if the element and its children should receive input; `true` if neither the element nor its children should receive input and should, instead, pass inputs to the elements that are visually behind the current visual element. `Default is false`.

What you need is to set `InputTransparent` to `true` on the text stackLayout .

```
 <StackLayout  InputTransparent="True"  Margin="0,10" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" BackgroundColor="SaddleBrown">
     <Label Text="{Binding name_norm}" TextColor="White" FontSize="16" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="15,-10,0,0" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
     <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="15,-8,0,0" BackgroundColor="Aqua">
         <Image Source="https://www.freeiconspng.com/thumbs/info-icon/info-icon-24.png" HeightRequest="15" Aspect="AspectFit" />
         <Label Text="{Binding name_lat}" TextColor="White" FontSize="16" FontAttributes="Italic"  VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="-5,0" />
     </StackLayout>
 </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the Problem. It was that before I put the red Flag on the Top and the text at the bottom in one Stacklayout which expanded from top to bottom. Now that i put them in seperate StackLayouts it works and the ImageButton is free.

Pictures before/after.

[old StackLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUnly.jpg)

[new Stacklayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjZzm.jpg)

The new XAML is:

```
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding plants}" HeightRequest="300" PeekAreaInsets="100">
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Frame  HeightRequest="280" WidthRequest="180" BackgroundColor="Wheat" HasShadow="True" Margin="10" Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" CornerRadius="10" >
                        <Grid>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <ImageButton Source="{Binding imgsource}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    Aspect="AspectFill" Opacity="0.9" Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked" />
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Aqua">
                                <ImageButton Source="https://icons-for-free.com/iconfiles/png/512/bookmark-131964752402712733.png" HeightRequest="35"
                                            Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="5,0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked_1" />
                            </StackLayout>
                            
                            <StackLayout Margin="0,10" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" BackgroundColor="SaddleBrown">

                                <Label Text="{Binding name_norm}" TextColor="White" FontSize="16" FontAttributes="Bold"
                                        Margin="15,-10,0,0" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" />

                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="15,-8,0,0" BackgroundColor="Aqua" >
                                    <Image Source="https://www.freeiconspng.com/thumbs/info-icon/info-icon-24.png" HeightRequest="15"
                                        Aspect="AspectFit" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding name_lat}" TextColor="White" FontSize="16" FontAttributes="Italic"  VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="-5,0" />
                                </StackLayout>
                                
                                
                                
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
```

New Question now. Since at the bottom there is the Text StackLayout, where the Text is I cant press the ImageButton. How can I put the ImageButton as top "layer" so I can also press it while pressing on the text.